# Get last updated time for DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there any way to get the timestamp for the most recent update on a DynamoDB table?

Comment: I just came across this question and I think the DynamoDB Streams might be in some cases useful. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html
I guess this is a recent feature

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No. This is not part of the DynamoDB api. Fortunately this is easy to implement yourself. Add a column to each item for each UpdateItem or PutItem request with the current time. This will insert the time according to your application servers instead of DynamoDB itself, but these ideally will be the same

Comment: But there is no guarantee that the clocks of all application servers will be in sync.

Comment: Of course not, synced clocks are a fundamental problem of distributed system design. 

Unfortunately, @Ajax did not speak more about his usecase so we cannot begin to guess the implications have in his system. I simply addressed his question as asked.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. The answer is 100% true. The alternative offered isn't perfect, but it's the best you can do given the constraints of ddb.

Comment: what if the item deleted from table? how do you update the time?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in an approximate time, you can get the timestamp of the write operations rounded to the nearest 5 minutes by looking at the `SuccessfulRequestLatency` metric for the `PutItem` operation inside Cloudwatch. You will see an entry on the x-axis only if there was a write operation in that 5-minutes time segment.

In the following screenshot, you can see that there was at least one write operation around 10:30 and 10:35, too:
[image]